# Parsing a very large JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

Realizing that this question has been posted before, I'm looking for a mid-2014 take on this problem.

What's the best way to parse a very large JSON object in a browser? For the sake of argument, let's say this object is at least 64 MB (that's text size only, before parsing into data types). Let's assume we aren't dealing with IE as well to save us all a headache.

I know of the following solutions:

1. Cut the response at server level into chunks and process them one at a time
2. Cut the response at client level which requires writing one-own JSON parser that does that

I can't do:

1. My JSON source is local and is parsed in the browser and then sent processed to the server. For various reasons, I can't do this differently.
2. Number 2 seems pretty tedious.

What do you think is the best way to approach this? Are browsers today better equipped to handle very large JSON objects?

Comment: Well, did you actually try it? What issues did you face?

Comment: And you are really sure, that parsing (not transporting) the 64MB object is the biggest problem

Comment: Did you try with web workers?

Comment: I never actually tried it because I never had the chance to. I thought I wouldn't design a system based on JSON until I'm sure it wouldn't have this limitation. Transporting won't be an issue because it will be done on a query-basis (one or multiple items at a time), and I can't really get around transporting it anyway, so no point of addressing it. I haven't tried web workers, no, but I'll definitely take a look at it. Thank you all for your suggestions :)